# SSRS 2016 Webservice LoadReport : The item cannot be found

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

SSRS report does not load when attempt to call via ReportService2005.asmx. Stacktrace below received even though it seems thatthe path is valid. We don't have this issue on a 2014 SsRS box. Any help appreciated?

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.S
oapException: The item '/ZambaReportsBLU/FORMALQUOTATION' cannot be found. ---> M
icrosoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item
 '/ZambaReportsBLU/FORMALQUOTATION' cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.LoadReport(Str
ing Report, String HistoryID, ExecutionInfo2& executionInfo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(St
ring Report, String HistoryID, ExecutionInfo& executionInfo)
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapE
xception: The item '/ZambaReportsBLU/FORMALQUOTATION' cannot be found. ---> Micro
soft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/ZambaReportsBLU/FORMALQUOTATION' cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.LoadReport(Str
ing Report, String HistoryID, ExecutionInfo2& executionInfo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(St
ring Report, String HistoryID, ExecutionInfo& executionInfo)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClie
ntMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCal
l)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodN
ame, Object[] parameters)`

Answer (score 0):

We installed a different instance of SSRS and this solved the problem. Not sure what the issue was really